# Moodle Quizes - How to Limit the number of questions per quiz attempt?

Tags: moodle

Let's say we have a published Quiz in Moodle and a learner attempts the said Quiz, all the Quiz questions are being asked.

Is there an way to limit the number of questions displayed to students?

Here are the example requirements:

- The questions need to come from a question bank that contains 20 items
- The Quiz needs to be 10 questions long
- The Quiz questions need to be fed randomly from the question bank
- Different users can answer different questions
- No users can see all the 20 questions from the question bank

Comment: I think some clarifications might be needed before posting an answer: Are you looking to limit the amount of shuffled questions in a quiz? limit the amount of question from the quiz navigation panel?

Comment: @CedricGuindon - say we add 20 questions in a quiz using a question bank. but we do only want the students to tested for 10 questions. that means real no of questions they answer should be 10. different students may answer different questions. Nostudent will see all 20 questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To recap:**
You need a quiz that contains 10 random questions from a question bank that has 20 questions in total.

The following are based on Moodle 3.5

**Here are the steps:**

1. Create your question bank, any questions you would like
2. Create your quiz, you should now see the following once you're in

> No questions have been added yet

3. Click on the "action" gear and "Edit quiz"
4. Click the "Add" dropdown and choose "+ a random question"
5. From the pop-up, choose the tab "Existing category"
6. Select your question bank from the category field
7. Apply filters if needed
8. Number of questions, choose 10 (assuming you want 10 questions)

you will see the list of questions from your question bank at the bottom of the pop-up

9. Click the button "Add random question"

You should now be back to you quiz edit page with your 10 random questions.
You can select the "Shuffle" option if you want the questions to be shuffled.

Now you're ready to test your quiz. You will have a total number of 10 random shuffled questions based on a 20 questions bank.